# templates, forward declaration, dll

Tags: c++

This is about the following setup of an application that uses (abstract) functionality from a *.dll and a static library and which causes read access violation at last (further details are provided below the code):

**... static library ...**

```
// InterfaceWrap.h 
//-----------

// dummy include
#include <SomeTClass.h>

template<typename T>
class InterfaceWrap
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeTClass<T>> m_somePtr;
    public:
        InterfaceWrap();
        ~InterfaceWrap();
        void AnyAction();
};

template<typename T>
InterfaceWrap<T>::InterfaceWrap() {
    m_somePtr = std::make_shared<SomeTClass<T>>();
}

template<typename T>
void InterfaceWrap<T>::AnyAction() {
    m_somePtr->SomeAction();
}
```

**... *.dll ...**

```
// Proc.h 
//-----------

// correct forward declaration?
class ThisInterface;

#include <InterfaceWrap.h>

class DLL Proc
{
    std::shared_ptr<InterfaceWrap <ThisInterface>> m_interfaceWrapPtr;
    public:
        Proc();
        ~Proc();
        InterfaceWrap<ThisInterface>* GetPtr();
};
```

```
// Proc.cpp 
//-----------

// what about forward declaration here?
Proc::Proc() {
    m_interfaceWrapPtr = std::make_shared<InterfaceWrap<ThisInterface>>();
}

InterfaceWrap<ThisInterface>* Proc::GetPtr() {
    return m_interfaceWrapPtr.get();
}
```

**... the application ...**

```
// main.cpp
//-----------
#include <Proc.h>

// dummy includes
#include <ThisType01.h>
#include <ThisType02.h>
#include <ThisType11.h>
#include <ThisType12.h>

class ThisInterfaceA {
    public:
    using Type1 = ThisType01;
    using Type2 = ThisType02;
};

class ThisInterfaceB { // not needed here but perhaps illustrative
    public:
    using Type1 = ThisType11;
    using Type2 = ThisType12;
};

using ThisInterface = ThisInterfaceA;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Proc proc;
    proc.GetPtr()->AnyAction();
    return 0;
}
```

The crucial intention behind this construction is to keep the `Proc` and `InterfaceWrap` classes as abstract as possible, i.e., having them not depending directly on a chosen "interface" like `ThisInterfaceA`. Moreover I would like to keep the feature, that `Proc` is not a template class.

Obviously there are problems, of which I'm not sure how to resolve them nicely:

1. The line `using ThisInterface = ThisInterfaceA` does not work as it leads to compilation errors for the dll source codes, basically saying that ThisInterface is not known. If however, instead of this line, e.g., `ThisInterfaceA` is replaced by `ThisInterface` directly, everything compiles and links fine, at least.
2. Even if everything compiles and links (compare 1.), there would ultimately occur a read access violation, which concerns `m_interfaceWrapPtr` or `m_somePtr`.

What I wonder in particular is, whether properly applied forward declaration is capable of resolving the above issues and allowing to keep the feature that `Proc` is that abstract (or even more?) and not a template class?

Comment: dll's and templates don't mix. you might export a full specialization (which I doubt). Dll export declarations should be restricted to c-types.

Comment: How can the application decide what the dll return? That's confusing. Can you just do a down cast?

Comment: @engf-010, sorry, did a little bit of a wrong pasting for the post (it's about only one dll basically). I just edited it. But I guess what you say still holds?  
... `DLL` is conditionally defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` somewhere else (left out), in case you wondered.

Comment: Whenever you use C++ stuff ,you create a (very) tight coupling between the dll and its potential users.
Baiscally both need to use the same compilerversion  (and more) ,therefore to make a dll universally usable you should only use c-declarations. And templates are basically a no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use real interface and [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

```
struct IAnyAction
{
    virtual ~IAnyAction() = default;
    virtual void AnyAction() = 0;
};

class Proc
{
    std::shared_ptr<IAnyAction> m_interface;
public:
    Proc(std::shared_ptr<IAnyAction> anyAction) : m_interface(anyAction) {}

    IAnyAction* GetPtr() { return m_interface.get(); }
};
```

```
template<typename T>
class InterfaceWrap : public IAnyAction
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeTClass<T>> m_somePtr;
public:
    InterfaceWrap();
    void AnyAction() override { m_somePtr->SomeAction(); }
};
```

and

```
using ThisInterface = ThisInterfaceA; // For easy/quick way to change concrete type for interface

int main()
{
    Proc proc(std::make_shared<InterfaceWrap<ThisInterface>>());

    proc.GetPtr()->AnyAction();
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. However, what if class `IAnyAction` needs to be templated, such that, e.g., `AnyAction` contains a templated argument, i.e., determined via the class `InterfaceWrap`, so that one has  `template<typename T>
class InterfaceWrap : public IAnyAction<T>`  
and `void AnyAction(T templateArg)` ?

Comment: Think about interface, not implementation. `IAnyAction` can be template, but you cannot have virtual template function. What I did for `Proc` can also be done for `InterfaceWrap` and so have interface instead of `SomeTClass<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, in what follows I provide the edited example code (from the beginning) as it finally works for me.
The solution is basically the [answer of Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64761068/14608000) (Perhaps this overall approach may not be the most elegant one, as pointed out in the other comments. However, I guess some purposes may justify it).

However, there is one little thing added: casted void pointer arguments. To me this turns out useful when extending the original problem towards, e.g., the member `AnyAction` having an argument of yet unspecified but "known" type.

**... static library ...**

```
// InterfaceWrap.h 
//-----------

// dummy include
#include <SomeTClass.h>

struct IAnyAction
{
    virtual ~IAnyAction() = default;
    virtual void AnyAction(void* arg) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class InterfaceWrap : public IAnyAction
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeTClass<T>> m_somePtr;
    public:
        InterfaceWrap();
        void AnyAction(void* arg);
};

template<typename T>
InterfaceWrap<T>::InterfaceWrap(){
    m_somePtr = std::make_shared<SomeTClass<T>>();
}

template<typename T>
void InterfaceWrap<T>::AnyAction(void* arg) override {
    auto thisArg = static_cast<T::Type1*>(arg);
    m_somePtr->SomeAction(*thisArg);
}
```

**... *.dll ...**

```
// Proc.h 
//-----------

#include <InterfaceWrap.h>

class DLL Proc
{
    std::shared_ptr<IAnyAction> m_interfaceWrapPtr;
    public:
        Proc(std::shared_ptr<IAnyAction> interfaceWrapPtr);
        ~Proc();
        IAnyAction* GetPtr();
};
```

```
// Proc.cpp 
//-----------

Proc::Proc(std::shared_ptr<IAnyAction> interfaceWrapPtr) : m_interfaceWrapPtr(interfaceWrapPtr) {
}

IAnyAction* Proc::GetPtr() {
    return m_interfaceWrapPtr.get();
}
```

**... the application ...**

```
// main.cpp
//-----------
#include <Proc.h>

// dummy includes
#include <ThisType01.h>
#include <ThisType02.h>
#include <ThisType11.h>
#include <ThisType12.h>

class ThisInterfaceA {
    public:
    using Type1 = ThisType01;
    using Type2 = ThisType02;
};

class ThisInterfaceB { // not needed here but perhaps illustrative
    public:
    using Type1 = ThisType11;
    using Type2 = ThisType12;
};

using ThisInterface = ThisInterfaceA;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Proc proc(std::make_shared<InterfaceWrap<ThisInterface>>());
    auto type1 = std::make_shared<ThisInterface::Type1*>();
    proc.GetPtr()->AnyAction(type1.get());
    return 0;
}
```